# Is it possible to shorten the path text in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I feel like this is sort of a silly question, but at my work I am often dealing with directories in projects that are deeply nested (e.g. > 10 directories deep) in the project's directory tree. When I'm working in Command Prompt, the path are often tediously long and take up a lot of space. Is there any way to shorten these paths in the Command Prompt window? Obviously it's nothing dire, I'm just not sure how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I looked it up, and I came across this: http://www.jakesee.com/2012/10/subst-command-line-tool-to-shorten-file-paths/ It seems like this SUBST command is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

use :

`subst g: c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g`

now you have `g:` to play with

Answer (score 0):

This won't shorten them, but one trick that I use is pressing TAB after typing the first few letters of the path. This will autocomplete the path for you. If the characters that you enter in match more than one directory, pressing TAB repeatedly will cycle through them all.